# How to get the name of a Spark Column as String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to write a method to round a numeric column without doing something like:

```
df
.select(round($"x",2).as("x"))
```

Therefore I need to have a reusable column-expression like:

```
def roundKeepName(c:Column,scale:Int) = round(c,scale).as(c.name)
```

Unfortunately `c.name` does not exist, therefore the above code does not compile. I've found a solution for `ColumName`:

```
 def roundKeepName(c:ColumnName,scale:Int) = round(c,scale).as(c.string.name)
```

But how can I do that with `Column` (which is generated if I use `col("x")` instead of `$"x"`)

Comment: `c.expr.toString`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if the question has really been answered. Your function could be implemented like this (`toString` returns the name of the column):

```
def roundKeepname(c:Column,scale:Int) = round(c,scale).as(c.toString)
```

In case you don't like relying on toString, here is a more robust version. You can rely on the underlying expression, cast it to a NamedExpression and take its name.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.NamedExpression
def roundKeepname(c:Column,scale:Int) = 
    c.expr.asInstanceOf[NamedExpression].name
```

And it works:

```
scala> spark.range(2).select(roundKeepname('id, 2)).show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

**EDIT**
Finally, if that's OK for you to use the name of the column instead of the Column object, you can change the signature of the function and that yields a much simpler implementation:

```
def roundKeepName(columnName:String, scale:Int) = 
    round(col(columnName),scale).as(columnName)
```

Comment: that works, altough I don't like to rely on `.toString`

Comment: Could you tell us why you need to define your function from the column object? I usually do things like that from the column name with `round(col(name), 2).as(name)`. Would it work for you?

Comment: thats a good idea, you mean `def roundKeepName(columnName:String,scale:Int) = round(col(columnName),scale).as(columnName)`?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is something I use quite often.

Comment: @Oli I'm defining a `ColumnExtension` class, with among other things, a `.toInt` method. If I took the string name of the column as the constructor parameter, it would conflict with scala's `.toInt` on strings.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you're saying. Can you provide your code? Maybe you can write a different question and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

With the solution way given by BlueSheepToken, here is how you can do it dynamically assuming you have all "double" columns.

```
scala> val df = Seq((1.22,4.34,8.93),(3.44,12.66,17.44),(5.66,9.35,6.54)).toDF("x","y","z")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: double, y: double ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+----+-----+-----+
|   x|    y|    z|
+----+-----+-----+
|1.22| 4.34| 8.93|
|3.44|12.66|17.44|
|5.66| 9.35| 6.54|
+----+-----+-----+


scala>  df.columns.foldLeft(df)( (acc,p)  => (acc.withColumn(p+"_t",round(col(p),1)).drop(p).withColumnRenamed(p+"_t",p))).show
+---+----+----+
|  x|   y|   z|
+---+----+----+
|1.2| 4.3| 8.9|
|3.4|12.7|17.4|
|5.7| 9.4| 6.5|
+---+----+----+


scala>
```

Comment: Is it me or you forgot to drop the x column before renaming? :)

Comment: if you drop x first, then you will get exception - cannot resolve '`x`' ..  df.drop("x").withColumn("x2",round($"x",1)).show(false) doesn't work.

Comment: Ok my bad then, I thought `df.withColumn("x2",round($"x",1)).drop("x").withColumnRenamed("x2","x").show` was working

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I found this solution (only works for pyspark though - I'm guessing it's because I'm accessing protected class members and Scala doesn't like it):

```py
from pyspark.sql import Column
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

def get_column_name(c: Column) -> str:
    try:
        return col._jc.named().name()
    except AnalysisException:
        return col._jc.toString()
```

In Scala I can't access `Column.named`, but I can reach the underlying `Column.expr`, but from there I can't get `Column.expr.name`. Maybe you can dig deeper from there and find some way around it.